# zoom in, zoom out on mkmapview shows the hidden mkannotations

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, mkmapview

i have a strange problem on my mapview.

I have filtering option on my map to show and hide some annotations.

using

[[self.gmapViewController.gMap viewForAnnotation:annot] setHidden:YES]; or

[[self.gmapViewController.gMap viewForAnnotation:annot] setHidden:NO];

and i center the map to a particular location when i filter the mkmpaview.

but the issue is ... when i try to zoom in or zoom out, the hidden annotations are getting displayed on the map.

how to avoid it doing that.

Could any one ..let me know the solution please...

Answer (score 0):

Why cant you remove the annotations and then again add annotations where you want instead of hidding and showing.

Comment: well, i have a search functionality on that map. So, while searching, i used to perform the search based on the hidden and visible annotations and if the serach matches the hidden locations, i used to make their status hidden=NO (visible). I dont understand why the hidden annotations are visible when i try to zoom in or zoom out. Is there something i am missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can't rely on specific annotation views to continue to represent the same annotation as the map view's boundaries change; it reuses them, much as a `UITableView` reuses its cells. What you need to do is change some property of `annot` itself as well as changing the hidden state of the annotation view that currently represents it, then check for that property and set the appropriate hidden state in your `MKMapViewDelegate` `-mapView:viewForAnnotation:` method as well.

Comment: well,
1.i am not using dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier since my custom annotations images are not setting properly.
2.I am already using some property of the annotation (my custom annotation) and hiding and un hiding the annotations.

so.. why would mapview shows the hidden locations when i try to zoom in or zoom out.